# Undefined index error

Tags: php

I have a PHP uploader script which handle multiple uploads. The script works well but I get this error below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: uploadedFile in C:\wamp\www\setapro\rmc_manager.php on line 52
```

The above error occurs on this line below:

```
$inFilesArray = ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
```

I have tried to do something like:

```
if (!isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'])){
$_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'] = '';
}
```

but it does not work. I wish to do something about the notice. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit: Part of my html

```
form action="rmc_manager.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input    type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000" />

Please choose files to upload:<br />
<input name="uploadedFile[]" type="file" class="txt" /><br /> 
<input name="uploadedFile[]" type="file" class="txt" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="uploadfiles" value="Upload files" class="btn" />
```

PHP Upload manager:

```
if (isset($_POST['uploadfiles'])) {
$number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
$number_of_moved_files = 0;
$uploaded_files = array();
$upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/Uploads/';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']); $i++) {
    if ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i] != '') { //check if file field empty or not
        $number_of_uploaded_files++;
        $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i];
        //if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'])){
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i])) {
            $number_of_moved_files++;
        }

    }

}

}
echo "Number of files submitted $number_of_uploaded_files . <br/>";
echo "Number of successfully moved files $number_of_moved_files . <br/>";
echo "File Names are <br/>" . implode("<br/>", $uploaded_files);
echo "<br></br>";
echo "<p> Please find the processed GGAs with dates in the Setapro project folder</p>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test `$_FILES['uploadedFile']` before `$_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']` !

EDIT : in fact, just test `$_FILES['uploadedFile']` ^^

Comment: sorry how do I test that? am new here. Can I do it by echoing?

Comment: You are using if()... Continue!

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this

```
$inFilesArray = ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
```

u should use the php function isset( ... ),

for example

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']))
```

Comment: I did as similar thing but did not add [name] which did not work.

Comment: Hi... i see that you have two file input as an array... What about the index to access and invoke the file properties, if there are two file inputs i think u have to use 0 and 1 as the index to access them from the php side because $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'] points to nothing...